# Why does QGIS creates multiple connections for PostgreSQL Server?

Tags: postgresql, qgis, postgresql-12

We have a PostgreSQL database with PostGIS running and today we ran into the issue that too less connections were available. Mostly we are using QGIS to access the database. We realized that issue because multiple users got the following error:

> FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

When checking the number of connections in pgAdmin I realized a thing I saw before, but as I never ran into problems didn't care too much about.

QGIS creates multiple connections to PostgreSQL for the same user to the same database.

**Now I am wondering why this is the case and how I can maybe change that behaviour.**

*Could this happen for example if a person got access rights to a database through different user groups?*

One approach might be the issue that some users run into that if you add layers to a QGIS project that was created before might ask you multiple times for your login credentials if those changed. This seem to me that probably different credentials are saved with the project and therefor multiple connections might be used. Can anyone confirm or dispruve this? - Suggestions for a test scenario are also welcome to check this.

**Any ideas, hints or soutions are welcome.**

By the way: Yes we increase the number of max_connections, but I want to understand why this happens and get closer to the core of the situation.

Comment: I just realised the same and it's quite annoying when you have connection limitations on the server ...

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested why this happens but assume it's because QGIS fires off multiple of requests to the database at the same time, therefore starting up multiple connections. The issue for us was that QGIS didn't seem to ever close the connections so even though they were all sat there idle we still hit the postgres `max_connections` limit,

Our solution was to install `pgbouncer` on our Ubuntu server that was running postgres.

```
apt-get install pgbouncer
```

add username and password with double quotes to /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt

```
"username" "password"
```

restart pgbouncer

```
systemctl restart pgbouncer.service
```

In QGIS, change the port of your database connection to `6432`

Connections from QGIS will now be pooled and reused by pgbouncer (default poolsize is 20)

You can modify config if needed here `/etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.conf`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and that idea with pgbouncer. The curious thing is that QGIS will not always open up that many connections. We have users with just one and others with multiple connections while only having one instance of QGIS open.

Comment: We only experienced this issue very recently, we have since discovered it was caused by some users updating to the latest QGIS version  which had some strange connection behaviour: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/53621
Although, your original issue predates this particular QGIS issue.